# How do I show the column value for a user in an embed?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, discord, discord.js

I want to show user xp from table userLevel

Here's the code:

```js
connection.query(`SELECT userXP FROM 'userLevel' WHERE userID='${message.author.id}`, err => {
        if(err) throw err;
        message.channel.send({embed: {
            color: 15844367,
            description: 
          }
        });
    });
```

I can't figure out what goes in the description to show the xp

Comment: What library are you using to connect to the db?

Answer (score 0):

```
connection.query(`SELECT userXP FROM 'userLevel' WHERE userID='${message.author.id}`, err => {
        if(err) throw err;
        message.channel.send({embed: {
            color: 15844367,
            description: userXP
          }
        });
    });
```

Comment: You should add some explanation of what your fix does.